# Как virtuemart связывает добавленные изображения с конкретным товаром?

Tags: virtuemart, joomla, mysql

[image]

Не могу разобраться, как он это делает. Провёл следующий эксперимент:

1. Сделал снимок БД
2. Добавил несколько изображений в карточку товара
3. Сравнил состояние БД ДО и ПОСЛЕ.

Изменилась только 1 таблица - #__virtuemart_medias. Логично предположить, что она содержит всю информацию, необходимую для определения принадлежности изображений тому или иному товару. 
Однако я не вижу в ней ни одного поля, подходящего для этой цели, т.е., ничего, что могло бы идентифицировать товар.
Вот её поля:

```
virtuemart_media_id  int(11)
virtuemart_vendor_id  smallint(11)
file_title  char(126)
file_description  char(254)
file_meta  char(254)
file_mimetype  char(64)
file_type  char(32)
file_url  varchar(1800)
file_url_thumb  char(254)
file_is_product_image  tinyint(1)
file_is_downloadable  tinyint(1)
file_is_forSale  tinyint(1)
file_params  varchar(19000)
shared  tinyint(1)
published  tinyint(1)
created_on  datetime
created_by  int(11)
modified_on  datetime
modified_by  int(11)
locked_on  datetime
locked_by  int(11)
```

Кто-нибудь знает - КАК?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

судя с тайо конструкции 
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "SELECT `file_url_thumb`
    FROM `virtuemart_medias`
    where `virtuemart_media_id` = (SELECT `virtuemart_media_id`
                             FROM `virtuemart_product_medias` 
                             WHERE `virtuemart_product_id` = '".$id."' LIMIT 1) 
    LIMIT 1";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->query();
    $row = $db->loadAssoc();
    echo $row['file_url_thumb'];

Я могу предположить что вы не смотрите на все поля таблицы так как там просто необходимо поле virtuemart_product_id, так же могу предположить, что список полей вы смотрите в каком-либо phpmyadmin и просто там есть постраничка.

Comment: См. снимок, приаттаченный к описанию. У меня Virtuemart 2.08.

Comment: У меня virtuemart 2.08. Если у вас тоже, зайдите в таблицу и посмотрите на её структуру (тут вряд ли нужно ДУМАТЬ - достаточно просто проверить).

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__virtuemart_product_medias` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `virtuemart_product_id` int(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `virtuemart_media_id` int(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ordering` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `i_virtuemart_category_id` (`virtuemart_product_id`,`virtuemart_media_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Есть связь получается много ко много, через табличку __virtuemart_product_medias

Comment: (not%20provided)![alt text] это ваш снимок?

Answer (score 0):

Ну как-как - в таблице _virtuemart_medias создается новая строка, куда пишется имя файла, строка получает новый virtuemart_media_id. Далее в таблице _virtuemart_product_medias создается также новая строка, куда вписывается virtuemart_media_id и virtuemart_product_id - так ясно? И так для каждой картинки. Т.е. соответствие по айдишкам. 
И еще один нюанс, который может нарушить работу данного запроса:
обратил внимание, что если поле file_url заполняется всегда и однозначно, то поле file_url_thumb заполняется в зависимости от настроек юзера в админке магазина, т.е. не однозначно. Частая ситуация, когда это поле file_url_thumb ПУСТОЕ!